# Showing $0<\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(1+x+t)}dt<\frac{2}{\ln(1+x)}$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I was going to give this problem to some of my Calc II students, but I realized that I can't even do this without using some tricks involving infinite series (which they do not know yet), and I now want to see if anyone has any ideas about how to do this problem. This is one of the extra problems from a chapter review in a Stewart Calculus book:

> Use integration by parts to show that, for all $x > 0$,$$0 < \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)}dt < \frac{2}{\ln(1 + x)}$$

I've tried most of the obvious choices for $u$, but none of them seem to work out very nicely. I've also tried some algebraic manipulation to turn the integral into
$$-\int\frac{-(1 + x + t)\sin(t)}{(1 + x + t)\ln(1 + x + t)}dt$$

for which you can take $dv = \frac{-1}{(1 + x + t)\ln(1 + x + t)}$ and $u = (1 + x + t)\sin(t)$ to get the nicer equation

$$\int \frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)}dt = -\left[\frac{(1 + x + t)\sin(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)} - \int\frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)}dt - \int\frac{(1 + x + t)\cos(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)}dt \right]$$

which gives you some cool equations, but is less than helpful. Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Than you all for your comments! This problem is from Calculus: Early Transcendentals 6th edition. It should be question 15 on page 523. And the particular challenge that I am having with this problem is finding a way that a Calculus II student might be expected to solve the problem. If we use some more advanced tools from analysis, this problem is not very difficult, but I'm really interested in finding the "lowest level" approach to this. More specifically, an approach that an average Calculus II student might be able to use if they were provided with some problem scaffolding.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the integral correctly? On the basis of numerical and graphical evidence, it appears to be divergent.

Comment: @A. E. Rosas It's convergent, since $1/\ln(1+x+t)$ is a monotone decreasing function of $t$.

Comment: Turns out it is not a chapter review problem. Instead it is a "Challenge Problem"   (for chapter 6) and needs several less-than-obvious steps.

Comment: @WillJagy do you happen to know what edition of the book this problem can be found on? I just checked 8 (mine), and it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: @A.E.Rosas I don't know yet, but the title is Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals.  second edition

Comment: As so often, it gets easier if you generalise. Let $f \colon [0, + \infty)$ a differentiable monotnically decreasing function with $\lim_{t \to +\infty} f(t) = 0$ and $f(0) > 0$. Then $$0 < \int_0^{+\infty} f(t)\sin(t)\,dt < 2f(0)\,.$$ Now there's basically only one thing you can do.

Comment: This question was from the Calculus: Early Transcendentals 6th edition. It's question 15 on page 523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this problem can be solved by taking $u = \frac{1}{\log ( 1 + x + t )}$, $dv = \sin (t)$. Then when you do the standard $\int u \,dv = uv - \int v \, du$, the $uv$ will evaluate to be less than the RHS of your original equation, and the $\int v \, du$ can be shown to be positive.

Comment: Well, it's a hint (and that's ok!), leaving the details as an exercise to the reader. There's a typo, it should be $\displaystyle u = \frac{1}{\log ( 1 + x + t )}, dv = \sin (t)\,dt$.

Comment: Okay, if we take $u$ and $v$ as given here, then we get that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(1 + x + t)}dt = \frac{1}{\ln(1 + x)} - \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{(1 + x + t)\ln(1 + x + t)}dt$$

and, I am not entirely sure how a Calculus II student would be able to deal with the right-most integral. Especially considering that the obvious comparison $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + x + t)\ln(1 + x + t)}dt$ does not converge.

Comment: @peabody I was thinking that an (advanced) Calc 2 student may be able to notice the denominator is strictly increasing and the numerator is a cosine function, starting  with positive values. This is enough to declare the integral to be positive-valued. If it does not converge then that part of the equation goes to $-\infty$, which would still satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Maybe not the most satisfying solution, but due to the one-step integration by parts simplicity I have to assume this is what the book authors intended.

Comment: Actually, I like Daniel Fischer's solution more

Comment: @peabody Erm... the derivative of $1/\ln(1+x+t)$ is $\displaystyle-\frac1{(1+x+t)\ln^\color{red}{2}(1+x+t)}$, so the resulting integral is absolutely convergent (though I doubt it's positive). Moreover, it was only given that $v'(t)=\sin(t)$, that does not necessarily mean $v(t)=-\cos(t)$. In fact, it's better to let $v(t)=1-\cos(t)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, this explains why things were going so wrong in my work: I failed at taking a basic derivative. Obviously, some more coffee is necessary in my routine. Thank you all for your help! I'm going to go ahead and mark this as resolved.